# What is R4DI0H34D saying?

Tags: cipher, knowledge

An organistion named **R4DI0H34D** has developed an new encryption system codenamed **G**.

Previous encryption methods include **V0C4l5** created by encryptor codenamed **Y0RK3**.

Here is some encrypted text we found, can you crack the cipher?

[image: Notes02.jpg]

It may be easier to see in text:

```
AADDDEEEGG
1312312313
ADEG
2222
AABDDDEEEeG
13312312333
AABBDDDEEEeeeGGG
1313123123123123
AADDDEEEGG
1312312313
ABBBBDDDEEEEGG
41234124123414
```

What does the text say?

---

*(Not part of the puzzle)*

I have tried to make this cipher as original as I can, so have fun and good luck!

Hint 1 (from comments):

> You don't need to know about Radiohead songs to solve this puzzle - not the song notes or anything, It's mostly a theme, so you can solve it without knowledge of Radiohead.

Comment: Is the repetition of "tried to make" part of the puzzle?  ~_^  $\qquad$

Comment: Just a thought...are the papers in the right order??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> AIRBAG - A song from Radiohead's album "OK Computer" [image]

Here's how I got that answer:

> The letters are the strings on a standard-tuned 6-string guitar, and the numbers are frets on those strings. If you map out these frets on chord charts, they make upside-down, capital letters. The R actually looks like a P, but I'm pretty sure it's Airbag since that's the title of a Radiohead song.

Step 1:

> Draw the shapes in reverse order, so that when you flip it, it makes sense.
>
>  [image: Draw the shapes in reverse order]

Step 2:

> Flip it and connect the dots.
>
>  [image: Flip it and connect the dots]

Comment: You are really close, just check your squares and try rotating the grid a bit more.

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake. I edited my answer :)

Comment: Ah, you got me... and I was so close... I just couldn't read the letters properly... I was getting "AIP8A_"... the last symbol made no sense to me no matter what way I turned it.

Comment: I added steps with pictures

Comment: "The R actually looks like a P", I think you made a little mistake there BTW

Answer (score 6):

Partial

> All the hints are simple l33t code.
>  This is about the music band **Radio Head**, the previous encryption method was **vocals** and the encryptor was **Yorke**(the lead signer.)
>  This is probably the lyrics of one of their songs. But I have yet to confirm.
>  Codename G might mean that the new encryption method is **guitar** and the letters A to G could be the guitar chords. The numbers under might be the number of repetitions before going to the next chord.
>  I suspect that e = Em(e minor)

Comment: Well done! You are *pretty much* on the right track!

Comment: @Melkor except that I can't play guitar and pretty much know no songs of radiohead. Unless I read the chord sheets of all their songs until I find it, it might be impossible for me. I guess the best way would be to just play the chords and recognize the song.

Comment: Not exactly. No spoilers but I tried to make it so anyone can solve who has a  very basic knowledge of the guitar.

Comment: @stackreader Sites like this http://www.drumbot.com/projects/key_chords/ may help.

Comment: I'll add to this that it look likely this is literally just one of the tabs for a song, so the numbers will denote which fret to play it on

Comment: You don't need to know about radiohead songs to solve this puzzle not the song notes or anything, It's mostly a theme, so anyone can have a go!

Comment: I'm guessing those letters refer to the strings on a guitar in standard tuning.  EADGBe.